# About orientation in splay trees in Robert Sedgweick

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

I am reading about splay trees by Robert Sedgwick. Following is text snippet from section

In the root-insertion method, we accomplished our primary objective of bringing the newly inserted node to the root of the tree by using left and right rotations. In this section, we examine how we can modify root insertion such that the rotations balance the tree in a certain sense, as well.

Rather than considering (recursively) the single rotation that brings the newly inserted node to the top of the tree, we consider the two rotations that bring the node from a position as one of the grandchildren of the root up to the top of the tree. First, we perform one rotation to bring the node to be a child of the root. Then, we perform another rotation to bring it to the root. There are two essentially different cases, depending on whether or not the two links from the root to the node being inserted are oriented in the same way. . Splay BSTs are based on the observation that there is an alternative way to proceed when the links from the root to the node being inserted are oriented in the same way: Simply perform two rotations at the root.

Additional information is present at slide 4 at following link

http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr04/cos226/lectures/balanced.4up.pdf

My question is

1. What does author mean by orientation here?
2. Request to given an example for orienations differ and orientation match.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Orientation simply means left or right child.

```
  A
 / \
B   C
   / \
  D   E
```

E is an example of the same orientation case - C is the right child of A and  E is again the right child of C. D is an example of differing orientations because D is the left child of C but C is the right child of A.

So you can describe the orientation of all the nodes with respect to the root node A as follows.

```
B left
C right
D right left
E right right
```

Comment: Isn't D is left left as D is left of B, and B is left of A. Similoary for E  it is left right.

Comment: No, what matters is the relation between a node and its parent. So at best you can say that B is a left and D a right descendant of A but that does not really matter here. D is right left because you have to first go right and then left to reach it from A.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are accessing node `n`, whose parent is `p`, and whose grandparent is `g`. Then the orientation is the same if both `n` and `p` are the left or right child of its parent.

So, for example, if `p` is the right child of `g` and `n` is the left child of `p`, the orientation is not the same. If `p` is the right child of `g` and `n` is the right child of `p`, the orientation is the same.